# Getting the first item from a Hashtable J2ME

Tags: java-me, hashtable

I'm trying to find the way to get the first item from a Hashtable that contains at least 5 elements. I've this:

```
Hashtable parkingSlots;

parkingSlots = new Hashtable();

parkingSlots.put("P1", null);
parkingSlots.put("P2", null);
parkingSlots.put("P3", null);
parkingSlots.put("P4", null);
parkingSlots.put("P5", null);


Enumeration gPL = parkingSlots.Keys();

While( gPL.hasMoreElements()){

    String parkingNum = (String) gPL.nextElement();
    **// Here I've this result:  P1, P2, P3, P4, P5  but I want to get only the first item, in this case P1**

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put a `break;` statement right before your final closing curly bracket (`}`).

Answer (score 1):

If you need one only, you can replace the while with an if, and that's all.

Remember two things: that Hashtable has no defined order and to define the parkingNum variable outside the block.. if you wanted to use it later.

```
...
String parkingNum = null;
if( gPL.hasMoreElements()){
    parkingNum = (String) gPL.nextElement();
}
...
```